# Can more options use "is"

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, collective-nouns

So I've been learning German on Duolingo (great app by the way if you want to learn a language). **I know you guys don't want translations here, but this is more about the English.**

Of course, not all translations can be word for word. The German sentence was

> Mehr Optionen sind immer besser.

I put this and got it wrong

> More options is always better.

Now, "sind" means "are" in German, but that's beside the point. Some things just work differently in different languages. I can understand "are always better" being right. But I think that **the concept of having more options** is always better. And I also think that you can shorten **the concept of having more options** to **more options**. To me, "more options" is a state that you are in in which you have better leverage and control.

Am I right? Does "More options" here take a singular verb?

Comment: I **think** you want to know whether a subject of *More options* can have a singular verb, right? What was the “right” answer supposed to have been, *are* instead? We have questions about that sort of thing if so, like saying “Is three scoops enough?” Also, you might care to join the [German.SE] site if you haven’t yet.

Comment: Duolingo is a terrible place.  You can't argue with it.

Comment: Lol @GeorgeCapote. Can you give me a reason why?

Comment: @tchrist Yep that was the question. That's a good point. Thanks. And I'll check it out.

Comment: Why you can't argue with it? Because it's not sentient.

Comment: Oooh. I thought you were saying I couldn't argue with your viewpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your analysis.

Indeed, your approach avoids the ambiguity that would be created by pluralizing the verb.

"More options **are** always better" could mean:

> 1) The concept of having more options is always better
>
> 2) The extra options are always better

"More options **is** always better" restricts the possible meaning to the one described at 1).

Comment: Thanks. I'll give more people time to answer, and if no one does, I'll accept yours.